# How to permanently uninstall an older version of CMake in Android Studio ? It gets auto installed as soon as project gets synced

Tags: android-studio, cmake, build.gradle, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager

I have 2 versions of CMake, 3.6 and 3.10. My project requirement is v3.10. However, whenever I uninstall v3.6 from SDK manager and again sync my project, v3.6 gets auto installed. And hence my build fails to compile as it picks v3.6 by default. Is there a problem with the setup configuration of Android studio? Someone please help me with a solution, as I'm new to Android Studio.